# Check if a string exists in an Immutable.Set<string[]>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, set, immutable.js

Here is a mock of what I have tried with each outcome... I've read over the documentation and it seems like at least some of these things should work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function getMatch(
  value: string
  fooSet: Immutable.Set<string[]>
): boolean {
  // Convert the Immutable Set to a regular JavaScript array so i can use includes
  const setArray = fooSet.toArray(); 
  return setArray.includes([value]); //TypeError: fooSet.toArray is not a function
  // Use the some method to check if value exists in set
  let valueList = [value]
  return fooSet.some((key) => key === valueList); // fooSet.some is not a function
  return fooSet.has([value]);  //has is only for numbers can't be used on strings
  return fooSet.some((key) => key.is(value))//Property 'is' does not exist on type 'string[]'
  let found = fooSet.get([value]) 
  return found ? true : false //fooSet.get is not a function
}
```

UPDATE SOLUTION: changed to Set<List> which was a great improvement @Bergi. The other half was i needed to compare immutable to immutable, my value was a 3 string key so this was the fix:

```
function getMatch(
  values: { key1: string: key2: string; key3: string }
  fooSet: Immutable.Set<List<string>>
): boolean {
  const { key1, key2, key3 } = values
  const valueList = Immutable.List<string>([key1, key2, key3])
  return containsValue = fooSet.some((list) => list.equals(valueList));
}
```

I can also just look for one value in the list...

```
const checkKey1 = (list: Immutable.List<string>) => list.includes(key1);
const hasKey1 = set.some(checkKey1);
```

Comment: "*Convert the Immutable Set to a regular JavaScript array so i can use includes*" - why would you do that? This goes against the very purpose of using a `Set`: constant lookup time. Also immutablejs `Set` already has an [`.includes()` method](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v3.8.2/Set/#includes()) itself!

Comment: "*`has` is only for numbers can't be used on strings*" - are you saying it throws an exception? That should not happen.

Comment: I suppose your actual problem is using a `Set<string[]>` instead of a `Set<List<string>>`, which [immutablejs would treat as values](https://immutable-js.com/#equality-treats-collections-as-values), whereas your `valueList` is not equal to anything but itself.